# Jenkins workspace standard and @tmp folders

Tags: jenkins

i have multiple big directories in the workspace directory in Jenkins, these directories are about a year old can I rm -rf these folders or it would break something? and what does it mean when i have the same folder name but with different ending such as @2 , @2@tmp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can remove everything without any concern. Of course, you'll lose all the job outputs and archived artifacts.

About `@2` folders, if I'm not wrong, they are created when there are concurrent jobs running.

Comment: _"you'll lose [...] archived artifacts." -- You don't loose archived artifacts because they are stored in the job directory, not in the workspace. Workspace can be considered temporary directory of a run. About `@n` folders you are right.

Comment: ok, then I'll delete the folders in the workspace that are more than 4 months old, and leave rather new for now, thanks for the insights. but do I have to delete it from the interface or I can just rm -rf from the directory folder?

Comment: Usually I delete them directly with `rm -rf`